# Pinnacle firewire card on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, lspci, firewire, video-capture-card

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and have a Pinnacle video capture card installed. I am attempting to download a movie from my DV camera. The card is seen by the system:

```
> lspci
  02:01.0 Multimedia controller: Pinnacle Systems Inc. AV/DV Studio Capture Card
  02:01.1 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Pinnacle Systems Inc. Device 0015
```

However, when I use `kino` or `dvgrab` my camera is not found. This is specific to Ubuntu as I have a dual boot with Windows and things work under Windows. What diagnostics can I run?

Answer (score 0):

Use `plugreport` to see a list of connected 1394 devices in linux.

I use it with `plugctl` to set channels to record more than one stream at a time with DVgrab.  Im not sure what to do if it's not listed in the output of plugreport, but if it is, you should be able to tell DVgrab exactly what channel to look for your DV camera on.  Also I would say that for sure until you see it in plugreport's output, it's not going to with with DVgrab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `dvgrab` as root, as the firewire devices are not accessible for unprivileged users. This causes a lot of confusion as the device seems to be connected and working fine, except the user can't access the device node.